# Ionic grid is being displayed inline

Tags: ionic2, grid-layout

I am just learning about ionic grids.
I am working in a windows computer, the ionic verion is 2.2.3

I tried to follow the very simple example in https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/ , section Equal-width. The logic is just like when using bootstrap, and I simply pasted the grid structure from there.

The result however is inline elements:

[image]

The code:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{::products.messages.title}}">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          1 of 2
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          2 of 2
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          1 of 3
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          2 of 3
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          3 of 3
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This was just a test, so that I could play around with grids, but I am already stuck at this point. The only thing I could think of is that the installed version of ionic does not support grids. However, it is 2.2.3, and grids are supported for ionic 2.

Comment: you seem to be mixing up ionic 1 and 2..there is no `ion-view` in ionic 2

Comment: @suraj  Ok, now I am a little confused. If the version of ionic is 2.2.3, doesn't that mean that I have ionic2?

Comment: do you have `ionic-angular` in package.json? what is its version?

Comment: @suraj well, I checked and there is no such package. I think I get it now that ionic2 is not the same as ionic version 2.x.x. Looks like ionic2 works with angularjs 3

Comment: I think you checked the ionic cli version which is different from your ionic framework version in your project..  You may have created an ionic 1 project...

Answer (score 1):

check as following. You missed the number of columns definition in `<ion-col>`

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>This column will take 12 columns</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>This column will take 6 columns</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: Not necessarily. According to the documentation, if no column width is defined, ionic will divide the whole row width equally for its columns. In any case, I also tried defining col width and still got the same result.